# Compact dataframe based on values of fields

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
  c1  c2 c3
0  A   1  a
1  B   2  b
2  B   2  c
3  C   3  d
4  D   4  e
5  D   4  f
6  D   4  g
```

and I need to transform it in this way:

```
  c1  c2  c3
0  A   1  a
1  B   2  b, c
2  C   3  d
3  D   4  e, f, g
```

I did it in this very inelegant and unpythonic way.

```
column_names = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']
dfcompact = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)
for c1 in set(dfout['c1']):
    c3 = ''
    for i in range(dfout[dfout['c1']==c1].shape[0]):
        c3=c3 + ', ' + dfout[dfout['c1']==c1].iloc[i]['c3']
    dfcompact=dfcompact.append({'c1': c1, 
                                    'c2': dfout[dfout['c1']==c1].iloc[0]['c2'],
                                    'c3': c3.strip(',')}, ignore_index=True)
```

Could you please suggest me a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend pandas groupby.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(  
    [['A',   1,  'a'],
    ['B',   2,  'b'],
    ['B',   2,  'c'],
    ['C',   3,  'd'],
    ['D',   4,  'e'],
    ['D',   4,  'f'],
    ['D',   4,  'g']],
    columns=['c1', 'c2', 'c3'])

df.groupby(['c1','c2'])['c3'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    c1  c2  c3
0   A   1   a
1   B   2   b,c
2   C   3   d
3   D   4   e,f,g
```